# getting an error cannot find symbol

Tags: java

i am writing a program that calculates the amount saved for someone bying a car. i have two classes the first one called called Carsavings2 compiles fine however the second class Crsavings3 seems to keep coming up with an error which says can not find symbol on the line where i am trying to instantiate the other class. i am new to java so its probably sumthin daft but i can not figure it out. Any help would be great here is how the code looks for both cladsses

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

public class Carsavings3 {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    double equalAmounts, l, amount, numberOfYears, carCost;
    Carsavings2 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings2(equalAmounts, l, amount, numberOfYears, carCost);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    //This will print out a request for the user
    System.out.println("Please input the cost of the car, a real number 0 or greater\n");
    //This will ensure the input value will remain between 0 and above
    carCost = read.nextDouble(); } while (carCost <=1);

do {
    //This will print out a request for the user
    System.out.println("Please input number of years, an integer between 1 and 10\n");
    //This will ensure the input value will remain between 1 and 10
    numberOfYears = read.nextDouble();} while ((numberOfYears<1)||(numberOfYears>10));
    }



    }
```

/*the errors i am getting are as follows*/

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\imran>javac Carsavings3.java
Carsavings3.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                carCost = read.nextdouble(); } while (carCost <=1);
                              ^
  symbol:   method nextdouble()
  location: variable read of type Scanner
Carsavings3.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                numberOfYears = read.nextdouble();} while ((numberOfYears<1)||(n
umberOfYears>10));
                                    ^
  symbol:   method nextdouble()
  location: variable read of type Scanner
Carsavings3.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                Carsavings2 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings2(equalAmounts, l,
 amount, numberOfYears, carCost);
                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable equalAmounts
  location: class Carsavings3
Carsavings3.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                Carsavings2 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings2(equalAmounts, l,
 amount, numberOfYears, carCost);
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable l
  location: class Carsavings3
Carsavings3.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                Carsavings2 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings2(equalAmounts, l,
 amount, numberOfYears, carCost);

 ^
  symbol:   variable amount
  location: class Carsavings3
Carsavings3.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                Carsavings2 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings2(equalAmounts, l,
 amount, numberOfYears, carCost);

         ^
  symbol:   variable numberOfYears
  location: class Carsavings3
Carsavings3.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
                Carsavings2 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings2(equalAmounts, l,
 amount, numberOfYears, carCost);

                        ^
  symbol:   variable carCost
  location: class Carsavings3
7 errors
```

*the following class compiles fine with no errors*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

public class Carsavings2    {

//variables
private double carCost;
private double numberOfYears;

//constructor 
public Carsavings2(double equalAmounts,double l,double amount,         numberOfYears,double carCost){

}  
public void equalAmounts(double numberOfYears){
    System.out.println("Equal Amount Method: \n\n");

    int l;
    double amount;

    for(l=0;l<=numberOfYears;l++){

    amount = (carCost/numberOfYears);
    System.out.println("Year "+numberOfYears+" saved this year: " +amount+ "total saved: " +amount+ "remaining: " +carCost);
}
 System.out.print("");}
```

}
*any help would be greatly appreciated. i have been trying to figure it out for almost 4 hours now an just not getting any closer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its nextDouble and not nextdouble.
2. You have declared variables inside main and using them outside main.
3. The call to the constructor should be inside main method.
4. You cannot instantiate an object of a class that way without having a parametrized constructor.
5. You need to initialize the variables before you can use them.

**EDIT**

```
 public class Carsavings3  { 

    //These are your class attributes.
    private double equalAmounts;
    private double l;
    private double amount;
    private double numberOfYears;
    private double carCost;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Here you are declaring a variable to use later in the method.
       double equalAmounts, l, amount, numberOfYears, carCost;

       // Then you assign values to those variables. You must always assign the variables you declare with some value before you can use them.
       equalAmounts = 0;
       l = 0;
       amount = 0;

       //numberOfYears, carCost variables are being initialized inside your while loops, so you need not initialize them here.        

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        //This will print out a request for the user
        System.out.println("Please input the cost of the car, a real number 0 or greater\n");
        //This will ensure the input value will remain between 0 and above
        carCost = read.nextDouble();
    } while (carCost <= 1);

    do {
        //This will print out a request for the user
        System.out.println("Please input number of years, an integer between 1 and 10\n");
        //This will ensure the input value will remain between 1 and 10
        numberOfYears = read.nextDouble();
    } while ((numberOfYears < 1) || (numberOfYears > 10));

  //This is where you create an instance of the class Carsavings3 using a parametrized constructor. You can use the variables declared and initialzed above here. But in order to use a parametrized constructor, you need to create such a constructor in your class.
  Carsavings3 Carsavings2Object = new Carsavings3 (equalAmounts, l, amount, numberOfYears, carCost);
}

 // This is how a parametrized constructor is written. A parametrized constructor is used to initialize the attributes of that class to the values passed as the parameters to this method.
private Carsavings3 (double equalAmounts, double l, double amount, double numberOfYears, double carCost) {
    this.equalAmounts = equalAmounts;
    this.l = l;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.numberOfYears = numberOfYears;
    this.carCost = carCost;

}
```

}

Comment: i have managed to get rid of te other errors but i have five errors now referring to each variable stating it has not been initialised but im nt sure werer i should be doing this...any ideas?

Comment: Right after the declarations.

Comment: in which class? sorry for the daft questions but im really confused now

Comment: The variables are first declared, then initialized and then used. You have the declaration and the usage. The initialization needs to happen between the two of them. You can initialize them anywhere you like after the declaration and before you put them to use.

Comment: as far as i can tell i have done that but the issue is still there. I have re edited the code in the question above to what i have done now, if you dont mind just having a look and see were i have gone wrong that would be great thanks

Comment: Check the edited section. Also read up on the basics of a class. Variable declaration,initialization and constructors to get a better picture of what you are writing.

Answer (score 2):

`read.nextdouble();` != `read.nextDouble();`

CapiTiLiZatiOn matters!

More importantly, you're style of coding needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code *early* and **often**, and to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

change this..

```
read.nextDouble();
```

and inside of `Carsavings2`   create constructor like this

```
public Carsavings2(double equalAmounts,double l,double amount,double numberOfYears,double carCost){

}
```

declare all field and initiate with this constructor..